# Gensim W2V - UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, gensim, word2vec

I trained and saved a word2Vec model 'myWord2Vec.model' to pass it to a logistic regression model for training, but the vector size is bigger than my training dataset so, I needed to reduce the vector size. I tried the code below:

```
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format('myWord2Vec.model', limit=2021)
```

It gave me this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

I have no clue how to fix it nor how to reduce the vector size.
I would appreciate the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How did you save `myWord2Vec.model`?

If you saved it with `.save()`, you need to load it with `.load()`, of the same model class. (And note: `.load()` is all-or-nothing, without any `limit=` option to just load part of the the set-of-vectors.)

Only if you saved with `.save_word2vec_format()` would it then be appropriate to load with `.load_word2vec_format()`. (And, trying to load the wrong-format file with `.load_word2vec_format()` could generate the kind of error you're seeing.)

Separately: `limit=2021` is a very strange option. Do you really want just 2,021 vectors loaded? (Usually people want at least tens-of-thousands to load.)

Also, your observation "the vector size is bigger than my training dataset" doesn't really make sense. Vector sizes in word2vec are most often 100-400 dimensions, if you have enough training data to support that size. You would more likely reduce the vector-size if you had *less* data, which was insufficient to train a higher-dimensional model. Reducing vector size *does* save a bit of memory. But, the model size is more a function of the vocabulary size (number of unique words) than training dataset site. And, if you truly have too large of a vocabulary to fit in memory, usually discarding lower-frequency words, by choosing a higher `min_count` option, is better than shrinking the `vector_size`.

Comment: Thank you it worked! I was saving the it .save indeed, when I changed it, it worked fine. Yes, my dataset is very small currently that is one of the project's challenges.

Answer (score 1):

In UTF-8 multi byte sequences start with a byte having bits 11xxxxxx and having continuation bytes 10xxxxxx. The error states that a continuation byte 0x80 = 10000000 was encountered at a start position.

This can happen on non-UTF-8 text/binary data, or when carelessly text is read buffered, and a buffer begin or end splits a multi byte sequence.

The limit could break the decoding, but I would consider checking the data first. You could try ISO-8859-1  to check what happens when the decoding passes silently.

0x80 at position 0 reeks of wrong data/wrong algorithm.